# ReactJs state is change, but iframe not change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react and I want to show a different pdf file on each menu in my application
this is my code

```
class document extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            folder_name: this.props.params.folder_name,
            pdf_src : ''
        }

    }


    menuClick(menu_name){

        var src ='';
        if(menu_name == 'Product'){
            src =  "assets/file/Product.pdf";
        }else if(menu_name =='leadership'){
            src = "assets/file/Leadership.pdf";
        }else if(menu_name =='motivation'){
            src = "assets/file/Motivation.pdf";
        }
        this.setState({
            folder_name : menu_name,
            pdf_src : src
        })

    }

    render(){
        console.log(this.state.pdf_src);
        let choosen_menu = this.state.folder_name || '';
        let pdf = this.state.pdf_src || '';
        let list_menu = [];
        switch(choosen_menu){
            case 'product' :
                titleMenu = 'Product';
                list_menu.push(<iframe src ={pdf} width='90%' height="800px" allowfullscreen></iframe>);
                break;
            case 'leadership' :
                titleMenu = 'Leadership';
                list_menu.push(<iframe src ={pdf} width='90%' height="800px" allowfullscreen></iframe>);
                break;
            case 'motivation' :
                titleMenu = 'Motivation';
                list_menu.push(<iframe src ={pdf} width='90%' height="800px" allowfullscreen></iframe>);
                break;
            default :
                list_menu.push(
                    <label> not found</label>               
                );
                break;
        }


        return (
            <div className="panel-body boxShadow">
                <div className="row loadresult">
                    <div className="col-xs-12">     
                        {list_menu}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>      
        );
    }
}
```

i have try to show the state of pdf_src, and the result is when i click on the menu, the state that show at console is change, but the iframe is still show the pdf that was first opened

can somebody help me with this, why the iframe is doesn't change when the state is change.

Any help would be appreciated thank you :)

Comment: After every render, i woukd suggest to remove eveything pushed to list_menu and then push to it.

Comment: i'm sorry, my fault
I think I accidentally deleted that part when tidying up the code, thank you @MohitTilwani

Answer (score 0):

finally i found the answer, if you want to re render the iframe in same component you must add different key for every pdf file, in my case i use src as a key like

```
<iframe key ={pdf} src ={pdf} width='90%' height="800px" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

i think when the key is change, the iframe will be re render.
thanks